# What's an optimal way to use a hash reference?

Tags: arrays, performance, perl, hash, reference

I'm working on a script that generates multiple large hash of arrays (HoAs) data structures. I'm trying to optimize my script as currently it's taking considerable amount of time to run.

I've done a bit of benchmarking. I've managed to make the script execution approx. 3.5 times faster by utilizing array references and reducing subroutine call overhead by using `@_` directly instead of copying it into a variable. I've also removed unnecessary subroutines and redundant variable declarations. Despite these improvements, I'd like to make the code run even faster.

At the start of my script I parse through a large file to generate two HoA data structures.
Which one of these approaches in regards to hash references is the most feasible and efficient? The HoA will look something like this:

```
%HoA = (
    'C1' =>  ['1', '3', '3', '3'],
    'C2' => ['3','2'],
    'C3' => ['1','3','3','4','5','5'],
    'C4'  => ['3','3','4'],
    'C5' => ['1'],
);
```

**OPTION 1**

Generate the HoAs as I parse the file (See below). Finally put the hash of arrays into a hash ref.

```
my $hash_ref = \%HoA;
```

**OPTION 2**

Parse the file such that each key in the HoA has a value that points to an array_ref. Finally put the hash of arrays into a hash ref.

==============

I feel like OPTION 2 is a good approach but how do I do this?

Here's how I'm currently doing it.

```
use strict; use warnings;
open(F1, "file.txt") or die $!;
my %HoA = ();
    while (<F1>){
    $_=~ s/\r//;
    chomp;
    my @cols = split(/\t/, $_);

    push( @{$HoA{$cols[0]}}, @cols[1..$#cols]);
 }
close F1;
```

I need an efficient data structure will facilitate me to lookup values and keys fast. Also, I need to be able to pass in the the key values (the arrays), the keys, and the HoA itself into subroutines as efficiently as possible multiple times.

Comment: you have a typo in your example: `my %HoA_ref = {};`. You've put the wrong Sigil, should be `$`

Comment: Please use scalar variables instead of Barewords as filehandle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't use global variables, including for file handles.
- You declared `%HoA` and never used.
- You declared `$HoA_ref` and never used it.
- You used `$HoA` without declaring it. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`
- Why create a reference you don't need and end up dereferencing it numerous times?
- There's no reason to assign an empty list to a hash you just created. `my %HoA = ();` is silly.
- Might as well combine the `s///` and the `chomp`;
- Either omit `$_` when not needed, or use a meaningful variable name.

All of the above and a few other improvements have been made to get:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '<', 'file.txt') or die $!;

my %HoA;
while (<$fh>){
    s/\r?\n\z//;
    my ($key, @cols) = split /\t/;
    push @{ $HoA{$key} }, @cols;
}
```

Comment: Normally, I would avoid opening the file in the script (using ARGV via `<>` instead), but I have the feeling this is part of a larger program where it might make sense.

Comment: thanks, I'm going try both ways to see which one clocks in at the fastest run time. I figure since I have several subroutines that use array and hash references as parameters option 2 might be a good approach. My subroutines processes the hash and array refs in scalar form. I don't dereference them in the subroutines.

Comment: You could always create the ref after populating the HoA.

Comment: yeah that was option 1. This might be another good approach. The only place in the code where I more or less dereference the HoA is when I want to pass an array_ref corresponding to a particular key into a subroutine. `foreach my $key ( keys %{ $href } ) { compute( %{ $h{$key} } }`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the any advantages/disadvantage of option 1 vs option 2. I'm almost done making the changes for option 2.

Comment: I showed you what I'd use, and for almost every line, I explained why I'd do it that way. No idea what you're trying to get from these comments.

Comment: Re that loop: That would be `compute( @{ $h{$key} } )` (hash) or `compute( @{ $h->{$key} } )` (hash ref). That whole thing could be written `compute($_) for values %h;` (hash) or `compute(@$_) for values %$h;` (hash ref).

Comment: Re option 1 vs option 2: I showed you what I'd use, and for almost every line, I explained why I'd do it that way. What more do you want? Do you just want to repeat that there's absolutely no reason to use a reference to `%HoA` in that code?

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that it's best to use references wherever possible.  Some additional notes:

1. If you need this, `$_=~ s/\r//;` for Windows eol compatibility, then you need a better perl build.  ActiveState's is usually the most robust.  `chomp` ought to take care of a terminal cr/lf, or rather the file read ought to have already converted the cr/lf pair to a lf only.
2. Perl `shift` is O(1) and very fast.  You can use this to your advantage here.
3. You can't tell in advance what will be fastest. Benchmarking of options is the only way to go.
4. Try reading the input file alone with no processing.  Once the job is I/O bound, optimizing doesn't help any more.

Here is what I'd start with:

```
 open(F, "file.txt") or die $!;
 my $h = {};
 while (<F>){
   chomp;
   my @cols = split "\t";
   my $key = shift @cols;
   push @{$h->{$key}}, @cols;
 }
 close F;
```

Comment: Don't pretend the first arg of `split` isn't a regex. The OP's `/\t/` is better.

Comment: The whole `shift` can be avoided by adding `$key` to the list assignment on the previous line.

Comment: @Gene if I wanted to pass an array_ref of a particular key into a subroutine called say `compute`, how would I do that? is it `foreach my $key (keys %{ $h }) { compute( %{ $h{$key} } }`?

Comment: Or is there an easier way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're attempting to do in your example.

```
open(my $fh, "<", "file.txt") or die $!;
my $HoA_ref = {}; # ref will return a HASH 
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    $line =~ s/\r//;
    chomp $line;
    my @cols = split(/\t/, $line);

    # shift off first element in the list to use 
    # as the key
    my $key = shift(@cols);
    # set value to an array ref of whatever 
    # is left in the list.
    $HoA_ref->{$key} => [@cols];
}
close <$fh>;
```

It's worth noting that `$key` will get overwritten if it appears more than once as you're looping through the file.

Comment: The overwriting problem is what I assume he is avoiding by using `push`, which always tacks the new items on the end of the list.

Comment: @Gene - You're probably right. The OP mentioned wanting `key => list_ref` data structure.

Comment: `[@col]` needlessly makes a copy of `@col`. Use `\@cols` instead.

Comment: The whole `shift` can be avoided by adding `$key` to the list assignment on the previous line.

Comment: These and other improvements are mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you are having large file, rather than using while loop, I would suggest doing a complete file slurping using module [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm).

File::Slurp read_file function tries to bypass perl I/O using sysread (check [read_file source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/URI/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm)) call.

`my $text = read_file( $file ) ;`